# Ruby upload files with a non libcurl library

Tags: ruby, sinatra, httpclient

Out of sheer curiosity, I'm using the following line to upload files to a Sinatra app:

```
curl -silent --location --upload-file #{file} http://0.0.0.0:3000/sent/
```

It works like charm. However if I want to use a pure ruby solution like [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient), what would be the code to get the same result? Can you give me an example?

**NOTE**: I'm not interested in **libcurl** related solutions. If there's another gem, except *HTTPClient* that can achieve this in **pure ruby** please share.

Best Regards

Comment: This question might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097491/uploading-a-file-using-ruby-nethttp-api-to-a-remote-apache-server-failing-with

Comment: The documentation for various Ruby HTTP clients show how to do these things. Did you read through them to check?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find any with a real world example @theTinMan

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) allows you to upload files. From the documentation:

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data('from' => '2005-01-01', 'to' => '2005-03-31')

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end

case res
when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
  # OK
else
  res.value
end
```

Add the body of your file to the `set_form_data` hash and you should be on your way.

Comment: Truth I already tried a similar code but doesn't work... Comes up with a 404 error no matter what. Thanks for your time anyway.